# can't disable nmi_watchdog

Tags: 12.04

Following directions from [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/disable-nmi-watchdog-when-using-pmu-event-based-sampling) and [here](https://katastrophos.net/andre/blog/2012/05/29/installing-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-on-fujitsu-u820-u2010-u2020/) I tried running `sudo echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog` but this results in `Permission denied`. I also tried setting the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nmi_watchdog=0" in /etc/default/grub but after restarting it has no effect I still see `/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog` set to 1. Finally I could not find the commended file `/boot/grub/grub.conf` but instead I found `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and I have no idea where the argument "nmi_watchdog=0" should be placed there.

Can anyone please advice how to disable nmi_watchdog?

Answer (score 2):

On runtime you can turn off nmi_watchdog as follows:

```
sudo su
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog
```

Answer (score 2):

Giovanni, you did almost everything to disable NMI watchdog. After altering "/etc/default/grub" as root (or sudoer), you should run "sudo update-grub".